# Image View find by Name

Tags: android

HI am trying to get an image view using the approach

```
int mId = getResources().getIdentifier(s, "id",getPackageName());
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById( mId);
        img.setImageResource(kBonusImage);
```

but I am getting 0 in mId.

Here is my xml layout:-

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/trFirstRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgFirst"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_border"
            android:gravity="center"
            />....
```

Comment: Please post the XML layout file that contains the `ImageView`.

Comment: I have updated the code, plz see the xml

Comment: What is the value in s?

Comment: Are you calling this after setContentView?

Comment: value in s is "image1" which i have set using image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFirst);

Comment: @C.d. yes, I am calling it after setContentView

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to load an `ImageView` with an `id` with the name`"id"`. However, the XML layout file does not have an `ImageView` with `android:id=@+id/id"`. This means that `findViewById()` cannot find the `ImageView` you are requesting. The specified `id` *must* exactly match one from your XML view file.

Using `getResources().getIdentifier()` is completely unnecessary. The typical way to get a `View` object in Java code is to use the `R.id` class which is generated from your XML layout files when you build your app. In this case, you have defined in your XML layout file a `ImageView` resource with id `imgFirst`. So you can call `findViewById()` like this:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFirst);
```

This assumes that you have previously called `setContentView()` to load the XML layout file which contains this `ImageView` resource.

Comment: I know that way , but I have created a number of images and I don't want to use that approach

Comment: @Zubair See my edit that explains the cause of the problem. I also suggest that you edit your question to explain further what you want to do. Do you want to find an `ImageView` based on the `id` stored in a `String`? Right now, you are just using a `String` literal which doesn't allow you to load any of the other images in your XML layout.

Comment: I have first created the image view in init(),  using  image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFirst);  and in another place I am trying to get the imageView using the above mentioned method

Comment: @Zubair If you already have a reference to the `ImageView` why do you need to get it again?

Comment: I want to setImageResources using a look where i can concatenate the name using "image"+i

Comment: 1. You can call `setImageResources()` on any of your already existing `ImageView` references. 2. Your OP does **not** mention anything about concatenating Strings to generate the `id`. When you do so, it must match one of the `id`s from your layout file. The error you get indicates that the id you provide does not do so.